# How do you create a map that has choropleths that will change with a timeslider?

Tags: cartography, time, choropleth

I have data for different countries over time that I would like to display in a choropleth map with a time slider that plays automatically on click.  What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question to expand upon what GIS software and version you are using (i.e. ArcGIS 10.1, or QGIS, etc)